# WordPress Site Deployment in Docker with Reverse NGINX proxy

Tags: wordpress, docker, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Wordpress site with a custom theme and plugins that I built locally.  It runs in docker container.  For deployment, I use NGINX running as a process on EC2 server as a reverse proxy for Dockerized apps.  I also use letsencrypt SSL certificates in NGINX.

After getting Admin UI to work over HTTPS, I find that my site is not loading asset files (css, scripts, images).

The following Gist shows all my files:

https://gist.github.com/vzelenko/ee1a1a5f833dbb94e9b0591e59df6ee8

Anyone knows why the site is not loading files with this config?

Comment: What's the error says when resources are trying to be loaded in your browser console.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the fact that you are not passing the files to the WP container try adding the files by mounting them :

```
 volumes:
   - ./yourcontent/:/var/www/html/wp-content
   - ./yourwordpress/html/:/var/www/html/
   - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
```

something like that

Comment: I doubt that you are correct on this...  Mounting wp-content directory would help with developing a theme locally, but it would not affect a running instance of WordPress if it was not done.

Comment: i don't have wp knowledge th wp-content was an exemple you just need to find where your template is and mount it ?  
@Farhad what did you mean by docker-compose is for local purposes ?

Comment: @MontassarBouagina - @Farhad's response is misguided.  There is nothing technically wrong with using `docker-compose` in any environment, but many orchestration tools (like puppet, kubernetics and AWS ECS) have comparable variations on it.